# Remove `not null` constraint during a migration

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, migration

I would like to cancel the mandatory of a field of my current schema. How can I accomplish that with a symfony migration?

Comment: Presume you mean with Doctrine as the ORM?

Comment: Indeed! I'm currently using Doctrine on my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations are intended to alter **database**, not schema. So you have to alter your **schema** yourself.

Also, for me best and cleanest way is to edit schema manually (just remove `notnull: true` on desired column) and issue `symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`. This will generate new migration class which you have to review and test (with `symfony doctrine:migrate --env=dev`).

Comment: Before anything else, thanks for the help! Your methodology sounds perfect to me but my symfony framework version is 1.2. As far I can test, the task that you mentioned is not present on this version.

Best regards!

Comment: Rui, run `symfony list doctrine` first. AFAIK, nevertheless symfony 1.2 contains Doctrine 1.0.x, migrations are available in this version.

Also, I strongly advice to upgrade to symfony 1.3.

Comment: Yes, migrations are available in my current symfony version but the previously mentioned task symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff is not. And yes, one of my top priorities is to upgrade for a higher version of symfony.